# make the 'sign up page' remember the username instead of the email

Tags: html

(I'm a non-native English speaker, so I'm sorry for bad grammar)

So my website has a sign up site, and for my login, I'm using an username instead of an email, but when you press "sign up", the browser asks if you want to save the email and password.

Is there any way to make the browser remember the username, instead of the email?

```html
<label> E-mail</label>     <br> 
        <input type="Email" placeholder="Required" name="email" required autocomplete="off">


<label> Username</label>
        <input type="Username" placeholder="Required (used For Login)" name="usern" required autocomplete="on">


<label> Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Required" name="psw" required>
```

I tried to use autocomplete="off", to see if that did anything, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I'll look into the link, thank you :-). This is my first time making a website, so I appreciate the help.